# Get count of Kubernetes pods that aren't running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I've this command to list the `Kubernetes` pods that are not running:

```
sudo kubectl get pods -n my-name-space | grep -v Running
```

Is there a command that will return a count of pods that are not running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add `... | wc -l` to the end of that command, it will print the number of lines that the `grep` command outputs.  This will probably include the title line, but you can suppress that.

```sh
kubectl get pods -n my-name-space --no-headers \
  | grep -v Running \
  | wc -l
```

If you have a JSON-processing tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) available, you can get more reliable output (the `grep` invocation will get an incorrect answer if an `Evicted` pod happens to have the string `Running` in its name).  You should be able to do something like (untested)

```sh
kubectl get pods -n my-namespace -o json \
  | jq '.items | map(select(.status.phase != "Running")) | length'
```

If you'll be doing a lot of this, writing a non-shell program using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) will be more robust; you will generally be able to do an operation like "get pods" using an SDK call and get back a list of pod objects that you can filter.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without any external tool:

```
kubectl get po \
  --field-selector=status.phase!=Running \
  -o go-template='{{len .items}}'
```

- the filtering is done with [field-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/)
- the counting is done with go-template: {{ len .items }}